# Android - animate view height changes.

Tags: android

Height is public property and thus has no setter. And so, I can't use it with ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder.
How can I animate height change of a view?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a ValueAnimator and add an UpdateListener that changes the height of the view for every animation update.